How to inject a Service inside ApplicationConfig?
How to inject a Service inside ApplicationConfig?
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(appRoutes),
    provideTransloco({
      config: {
        availableLangs: ['en', 'ru', 'kk'],
        defaultLang: LanguageService.getDefaultLanguage(),
        reRenderOnLangChange: true,
        prodMode: !isDevMode(),
      },
      loader: TranslocoHttpLoader,
    }),
  ],
};

Here, I want to use LanguageService
I used:

defaultLang: (new LanguageService).getDefaultLanguage(),
defaultLang: inject(LanguageService).getDefaultLanguage(),

All of them shows injection context error
So, is it possible to use Service inside ApplicationConfig?

Is the default language just a constant, or is there logic to generate it? In the latter case, does this logic depend on other services?

As far as I know, it is not possible to defer the environment providers initialization until you fetch the data using app_initializer so I fetch the API  get the default language and then bootstrap the application after the response has been received.
export function initializeApp(): Promise<any> {
  // fetch("https://someUrl.com/api/user") // <- place your API here!
  return firstValueFrom(
    of({ defaultLang: 'en' }) // simulate api call
  );
}

initializeApp().then((data: any) => {
  bootstrapApplication(App, {
    providers: [
      provideHttpClient(),
      provideTransloco({
        config: {
          availableLangs: ['en', 'es'],
          defaultLang: data.defaultLang,
          // Remove this option if your application doesn't support changing language in runtime.
          reRenderOnLangChange: true,
          prodMode: false,
        },
        loader: TranslocoHttpLoader,
      }),
    ],
  });
});

Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  APP_INITIALIZER,
  makeEnvironmentProviders,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClient, provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { provideTransloco, TranslocoModule } from '@jsverse/transloco';
import { firstValueFrom, tap, of } from 'rxjs';
import { TranslocoHttpLoader, LanguageService } from './transloco-loader';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [TranslocoModule],
  template: `
  asdf
  <ng-container *transloco="let t">
      <p>{{ t('home') }}</p>
  </ng-container> 
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

export function initializeApp(): Promise<any> {
  // fetch("https://someUrl.com/api/user") // <- place your API here!
  return firstValueFrom(
    of({ defaultLang: 'en' }) // simulate api call
  );
}

initializeApp().then((data: any) => {
  bootstrapApplication(App, {
    providers: [
      provideHttpClient(),
      provideTransloco({
        config: {
          availableLangs: ['en', 'es'],
          defaultLang: data.defaultLang,
          // Remove this option if your application doesn't support changing language in runtime.
          reRenderOnLangChange: true,
          prodMode: false,
        },
        loader: TranslocoHttpLoader,
      }),
    ],
  });
});

Stackblitz Demo

If the default language is just a constant or can be generated with simple logic without needing to inject other Services, you can just move the constant / function out of the service into a JavaScript variable / function.
export const defaultLanguage = 'en';
export function getDefaultLanguage(): string {
  // some logic
  return language;
}

Those can be used in the application config without any DI issues:
import { getDefaultLanguage } from './path-to-ts-file';

provideTransloco({
  config: {
    availableLangs: ['en', 'ru', 'kk'],
    defaultLang: getDefaultLanguage(),
    reRenderOnLangChange: true,
    prodMode: !isDevMode(),
  },
}),

